# What's better for performance, a CDN or a Server in each region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cdn

I've recently taken over a project that is a series of small WordPress sites, hosted on multiple servers across multiple AWS regions. Each site satisfies a different market, Asia, UK, America, Australia. They are actually all one codebase, with different themes - so could easily be a multi site.

I'm looking to reduce costs for the client, and simplify maintenance, so I think it makes sense to consolidate the current servers, beef up caching and stick a Cloudfront CDN in front, however I'm finding it hard to do a cost benefit analysis because I'm not sure how to compare the two.

Any recommended resources, or recommendations in general?

Note: This is for static anonymous users. Only admin can login to the sites, and so the latency issue would be taken into account for them.

Comment: It is entirely dependent on how well you can cache the content. If the content rarely changes and you can really crank up the cache settings then a CDN will be much better.

Comment: I agree with @MarkB above, it depends on your caching.  Normally I would go with a CDN.  Unlike availability zones, regions are essentially  independent, so it's difficult to share resources across regions.  Since CloudFront has edge locations all over the world, that can work considerably easier than separate servers in each region.

Comment: Don't overlook the possibility of doing both.  CloudFront automatically routes the browser to the nearest edge, but Route 53 geo-routing of the origin hostname on the back side will allow CloudFront to connect to a server in the region nearest the CloudFront edge handling the request, to fetch content not in the edge's cache.  But the pricing structure tends to make CloudFront kind of a no-brainer no matter what else you do, at least in some regions.

Comment: Your best bet is to just test it and gather actual metrics. CloudFlare could also be a solution if you don't mind handing over control of DNS. CloudFlare also has a plugin for WordPress that might have some benefit: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/227634427 You can also perform different performance tests against CloudFront and CloudFlare using https://cloudharmony.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I'm doing cross-region deployment with a site with quite a bit of dynamic contents.

Think of it this way: If your user makes a request, it'll still needs to be routed to your server, and CDN isn't helping much. Theo only advantage that I can see is with TLS, but it's also significantly reduced with servers in each region.

As Michael commented, in some regions the traffic out is slightly cheaper with Cloudfront, but it's not very significant in my opinion.

Another thing to consider is that if your site is just a WordPress site and has no dynamic content, CloudFront is an easy choice.